# NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 when calling .trigger()

Tags: jquery, triggers

A fellow  stackoverflow person show me how to load an html content into my DIV
content of Jquery Mobile. [MY question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17812398/1066131)

I tried to make a generic function  by passing the filename to get and the jquery selector where to insert the loaded file.

```
function showPasswordReset(filename, selector) {
     // incldue template
     $.get(filename, function(template) {
         $(selector).html(template);
         $(selector).trigger("create");
});
```

But on Chrome , I got the folllowing error

**Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 **

and it pointed to

```
 $(selector).trigger("create");
```

What Am I doing wrong ????

Thanks

Comment: The error clearly says that the element was not in the DOM or you were passing in the wrong selector when you tried to trigger the event..Can you show where you are calling the function `showPasswordReset`

Comment: @Sushanth

Hi, I am calling it from `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#pageChoixVisu", function(e, data) { getPageContent("pageChoixVisu.jsp", "#pageChoixVisu"); }); }); </script>`

Comment: I figured out, cache problem of Chrome !